# can some one exploit my below unserialize code

Tags: php, serialization

As per PHP.net manual on `unserialize` ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php ) and after few google search found - `unserialize` code can be exploited.

I don't have much information about on how hackers can exploit `unserialize` code. I am just scared, since I am using unserialize code that is coming from external user input.

**Below is my code, I want to know if this code can be exploited:**

```
<?php

if(filter_var($_GET['url'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {

    // $_GET['url'] = 'http://example.com/page/1.html'
    $html = file_get_contents($_GET['url']); 

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $encode = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $doc->loadHTML($encode);
    libxml_clear_errors();

    $nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
    $title = strtolower($nodes->item(0)->nodeValue);

    // storing in mysqli database
    // hiding mysql code.. 
    $serialize = serialize(['icon' => 'check', 'data' => $title]);

    // fetching from mysqli database.
    // hiding other mysql code..
    $row = $fetch->fetch_assoc();
    $unserialize = unserialize($row['title']);
}
```

**Can hacker craft "malicious title" tag and provide his URL to exploit my unserialize code?**

**Update:** I am using `PDO` for mysql, that is not problem. My concern is about unserialize code that is coming from external website `title` html tag, for which I have no control.

Comment: You're only unserializing what you yourself serialized, so the risk is significantly mitigated. What's more important is whether or not you're using prepared statements with bound parameters for your database interaction.

Comment: Yes, I am using `PDO`, that is not problem. My concern is about `unserialize` code that is coming from external website title html tag, for which i have no control.

Comment: Using PDO doesn't automatically eliminate SQL injections. If you're building queries with string concatenation then you're still vulnerable. The risk associated with unserialize comes from unserializing *untrusted* input -- you're not doing that. You're unserializing data that *you* serialized.

Comment: @AlexHowansky, My `PDO` is safe - I am sure for that. My concern is `unserialize` exploit for which there are lots of google search result and php warns about.

Comment: There's an explanation on object injection on [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Object_Injection) you might want to read

Comment: If you're using PDO and prepared statements, then why are you using `serialize()` (presuming `$title` is a simple string)?

Comment: I am storing array and it needs to be serialized.

Comment: And what exactly are you doing with the `$unserialize` variable after this? If you're just `echo`ing that out somewhere in your HTML _while_ the `$row['title']` comes from external input _(doesn't matter if serialized during its travels or not)_, you're making yourself vulnerable to [XSS injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Comment: @Smuuf I am doing `htmlentities($row['title'])` no change of xss.

Comment: The majority of code we have seen insecurely using unserialize could just as easily patch their code by changing how they hand off the data from a serialized object to a JSON representation of the values. In some cases simply replace serialize() with json_encode() and unserialize() with json_decode() is the only change that needs to be made.

Comment: Good question for: https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: why don't you use `json_encode` and `json_decode`, you know the array keys which are they so you can check the `json_decoded` data if containing the proper keys you expect. In addition if you know what kind of data you expect per array `key` e.g. `object`,`array`,`string` or `number` you could write a simple function validating those too.

Comment: What i think is that, the URL you are fetching through GET is been only validated for valid URL format but not for the URL that are safe to be fetched. What if the URL that is passed through GET parameter is valid URL but not the safe URL that you expected.

Comment: `Can hacker craft "malicious title" tag and provide his URL to exploit my unserialize code?` *YES* ***IF AND ONLY IF*** there are classes defined with magic methods containing vulnerable code. However, such exploits will require a knowledge of your code, and/or libraries/frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an attacker is able to somehow get a specifically crafted string directly into your database, perhaps through a secondary, unrelated vulnerability, then `unserialize`ing that string while you fetch it from the database can lead to an object/code injection.

You can only trust the data you're unserialising if you're sure you have also serialised it yourself before. Now, how *can* you be sure that the data you fetch from the database has been serialised by a trusted party before? This depends on *the entire rest of the system* offering no exploitable way for an attacker to bypass serialisation. Essentially, you *cannot* be sure who has serialised the data that's in your database. Tiny missing sanity check over here plus harmless looking code over there can in combination lead to a vulnerability.

The better solution is to use an exploit-free data format like JSON. It purely describes *data*, and there's no chance to inject anything code-related into it.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of very good comments, I'm surprised nobody made an answer already.

> Can hacker craft "malicious title" tag and provide his URL to exploit my unserialize code?

No.

I'm assuming you are refering to [PHP Object Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Object_Injection) vulnerability. This is about directly unserializing untrusted input. In this case you are unserializing something you serialized yourself, so you're good. Here is how it'll play out:

1. an attacker crafts a malicious title
2. you serialize it
3. you unserialize it - at this point it is still the same malicious title *as a string*. You would need to unserialize it a second time so it becomes an object and your code is at risk.

I would recommend using JSON anyway, as it is more standard (easier to use from another language for example).

Now the real question would be:

> can a hacker craft a malicious title tag to exploit *something* (not necessarily `unserialize`)

The answer is **yes** and that is why you always need to protect against XSS and SQL Injection when using the title provided by the user.

That being said, **the real vulnerability** in my opinion is in the way you validate the URL. `filter_var($_GET['url'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)` will happily validate a URL such as `file:///var/www/index.html`. So your code allows the user to read any file on your server.

It's also true for other protocols such as `ftp://`, `ssh://`, and so on. It's completely open to abuse.

Comment: *"No."* – …with an asterisk. The security depends on the fact that you actually do the serialisation yourself before. If there's some other vulnerability that might allow an attacker to inject an unserialised string into the right column in the database, they could leverage this `unserialize` call to do object injection…

Comment: @deceze I upvoted your comment, but OP specifically asked about *crafting a malicious title and providing its URL*. The answer to that, based on the code OP showed, is "No". Now if we are going to assume other vulnerabilities elsewhere is the system, then *everything* is possible...

Comment: Agreed. The specific way the question is phrased, the answer is no. The reality is that security ain't that easy.

Comment: @deceze "*The reality is that security ain't that easy.*" Amen to that!